# Is there any way to download Google Colab and run it on Ubunu completely offline?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any way to download Google Colab and run it on a local machine completely offline?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no chance of it, might be a bit off-topic but I guess the nearest you can achieve is to maybe run jupiter notebooks.